# How to compute Cohen's d and p-value for comparison of least squares mean from two different mixed models?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, treatment-effect, lsmeans

I have two randomly assigned treatment interventions (A and B), and two subgroups of individuals (X and Y). This is a longitudinal study with dropout. I want to test whether the outcomes of individuals treated with B are different in subgroups X vs. Y. I know how to compute the "least squares means" and average treatment effects (which account for missing data) for A vs. B. These are computed with a mixed model with fixed effects for timepoint, the baseline value, treatment group, timepoint*baseline, timepoint*group.

So one option is to run the mixed model on subgroup X (some of whom received A, and others B), and again on subgroup Y. That gives me LS means and standard errors for all four subsets (A+X, A+Y, B+X, B+Y).

At this point, how do I compare the B+X and B+Y groups? I would like to compute a Cohen's d and p-value.

Possibly relevant question: [Pairwise comparison of least squares means from two separate generalized linear mixed-effects models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212181/pairwise-comparison-of-least-squares-means-from-two-separate-generalized-linear)

Comment: The hard part of this question is deciding what SD belongs in the denominator. With mixed models, it is not at all obvious which of two or more variance estimates to use, or some combination of them. Good luck -- I don't have any useful advice to offer other than telling you it isn't a well defined question.

Comment: Thanks @RussLenth. What do you think of the following approach: run the mixed model `OUTCOME ~ BASE + TRT + WEEK + WEEK*BASE + WEEK*TRT + SUBGROUP + SUBGROUP*WEEK + SUBGROUP*TRT + SUBGROUP*TRT*WEEK + (1|SUBJID)`? Then, compute LSmeans for each combination of TRT/SUBGROUP and compute Cohen's d via the eff_size function in emmeans.